# ActionBarSherlock 4.0 doesn't work. But 3.5.1 do

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

If I use ActionBarSherlock 3.5.1 everything is fine and workes. But if I want to use 4.0 RC1 I got errors.

```
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'.
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'.
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values/abs__styles.xml:101: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse'.
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse'.
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values/abs__styles.xml:244: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:88: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse'.
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values-v14/abs__styles.xml:105: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2012-02-25 10:08:19 - SherlockApp] /home/leandros/workspace/ActionBarSherlock40/res/values-v14/abs__themes.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Be sure to set the Target API Level (of both the ActionBarSherlock project and yours) to 15. To do this:

1. Change android:targetSdkVersion to "15" in both AndroidManifest.xml files.
2. Change the build target to "Android 4.0.3" (or an equivalent 3rd-Party API) using the Project Properties (probably also of both ActionBarSherlock and your project).

I didn't find any documentation of this change, but just found out by trial 'n' error.

Comment: Solution is right. Solvev on my own yesterday. But thanks anyway.
But can't answer my own question :)

Comment: also if using IntelliJ IDEA then set the Module SDK's to 4.0.3+ for the same effect :)

Comment: Am getting this after I followed your steps : E/AndroidRuntime(1508): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xxxx.XXXXActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/xxx.xxx-2/pkg.apk]

Comment: Jake really needs to do automated builds using ANT so he knows when he breaks stuff. I'm using his lib as a Git Submodule, and I don't want to wait to get fixes like this and have my stuff broken.

Comment: I did everything like described but I still get `no resource found [...]` on `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"`. Maybe you know what else it could be?

Comment: For ActionBarSherlock 4.1.0-0, setting the target to 16 or 14 doesn't work. Only 15 (4.0.3) works.

Comment: I'm getting ActionBarSherlock from Maven so can't change the source. Have the same error.

Comment: I think ABS is used for making ActionBar and more in older version of android like android 2.2   .So now what is a use if we need to make our project in 4.0 !

Answer (score 5):

Setting the **Java compliance-level** (Project > Properties) to **1.6** (instead of 1.5) did the job for me.

Changing the API level didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on library -> Properties -> Android -> Set the project build target to latest

follow the same for your project.

Now clean both library and project, this should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use same

android:minSdkVersion="?"
android:targetSdkVersion="?"

values both of your project and the library project sholud be solve. After then do not forget to change 
android.target = ? (MAX VALUE)
in project.properties file.