# Refer to ActionBarSherlock from a library

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ActionBarSherlock 4.0 doesn't work. But 3.5.1 do.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442781/actionbarsherlock-4-0-doesnt-work-but-3-5-1-do)

I'm trying to use ActionBarSherlock for my app, but there seems to be a problem when referring to ActionBarSherlock from another library project.

It's because I use a UI project where I create all the activities, but this project is actually a library. So I need the ActionBarSherlock components in this UI project, but when I refer to ActionBarSherlock the following errors appear:

```
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:15: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:17: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView.Inverse'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values\abs__styles.xml:89: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerPadding'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values\abs__styles.xml:88: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:showDividers'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar.Inverse'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values\abs__styles.xml:101: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:43: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:51: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionMode'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionMode.Inverse'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupMenu'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupMenu'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values\abs__styles.xml:184: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:dividerPadding'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values\abs__styles.xml:183: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:showDividers'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values\abs__styles.xml:213: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:spinnerMode'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:63: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Spinner'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:68: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:70: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:73: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.PopupWindow'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.PopupWindow'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values\abs__styles.xml:257: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:animationResolution'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:78: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:85: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values\abs__styles.xml:305: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:88: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:91: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:95: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:99: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Title.Inverse'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:103: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:105: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle.Inverse'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:108: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:112: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:114: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:116: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v11\abs__themes.xml:10: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:14: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarWidgetTheme'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values\abs__themes.xml:183: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values\abs__themes.xml:184: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionModeOverlay'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values\abs__themes.xml:185: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Dialog'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values\abs__themes.xml:209: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values\abs__themes.xml:210: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionModeOverlay'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values\abs__themes.xml:211: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside'.
...\ActionBarSherlockLibrary\res\values-v14\abs__themes.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog'.
```

So it seems like it can not find the Holo themes, even though all the projects have `android:targetSdkVersion="15"`. Is there a fix for this or is it just not possible to refer to ActionBarSherlock from a library?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I solved by changing the **Project Build Target** of **both** the ActionBarSherlock **library** and **my projects** to Android 4.0.3 (**API 15**).

You can do this using the **Project Properties** and clicking on the **Android section**.

Remember to do a **Project Clean** after changing the API Level.

Comment: This solution works! Thank you very much! But when I deploy my project on a pre ICS device it shows a red cross in front of the Android version which gave me some doubts, but it runs fine anyway. Does that red cross have any consequences?

Comment: You should indicate the minSdkVersion you want to support inside the Android Manifest:
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

Comment: I did everything like described but I still get `no resource found [...]` on `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"`. Maybe you know what else it could be?

Comment: why 15? the site says 14 :   The library itself must be built against Android 4.0 (API level 14). Your project should be built using the latest version of the SDK as possible as long as it is 4.0 or newer.

Comment: Also, make sure you have a reference to Mono.Android.Support.v4 in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ABS to your library project as well as your other project.