# Resource not found error while using ActionBarSherlock version 4.1?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have added ABS as a library project to my android application and set target version for both library and my project to **API 15**, still I am getting these error.Could Anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml:21: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'paddingLeft' with value '@dimen/abs__dropdownitem_text_padding_left').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml:21: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_height' with value '?attr/searchResultListItemHeight').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_width' with value '@dimen/abs__dropdownitem_icon_width').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml:38: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '?attr/searchViewEditQuery').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml:38: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '?attr/searchViewEditQueryBackground').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml:62: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textAppearance' with value '?attr/textAppearanceSearchResultSubtitle').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_dropdown_item_icons_2line.xml:78: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textAppearance' with value '?attr/textAppearanceSearchResultTitle').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:41: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '?attr/searchViewSearchIcon').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:41: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'contentDescription' with value '@string/abs__searchview_description_search').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:63: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_width' with value '@dimen/abs__dropdownitem_icon_width').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:63: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_marginLeft' with value '@dimen/abs__dropdownitem_text_padding_left').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:63: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '?attr/searchViewSearchIcon').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:75: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '?attr/searchViewTextField').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '?attr/searchAutoCompleteTextView').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'minWidth' with value '@dimen/abs__search_view_text_min_width').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'paddingLeft' with value '@dimen/abs__dropdownitem_text_padding_left').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'paddingRight' with value '@dimen/abs__dropdownitem_text_padding_right').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'contentDescription' with value '@string/abs__searchview_description_query').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:106: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '?attr/selectableItemBackground').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:106: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '?attr/searchViewCloseIcon').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:106: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'contentDescription' with value '@string/abs__searchview_description_clear').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:121: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '?attr/searchViewTextFieldRight').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:128: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '?attr/selectableItemBackground').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:128: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '?attr/searchViewGoIcon').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:128: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'contentDescription' with value '@string/abs__searchview_description_submit').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:142: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '?attr/searchViewVoiceIcon').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:142: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '?attr/selectableItemBackground').
[2013-04-03 13:00:25 - com.hello.home.Login] C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Workspace\library\res\layout\abs__search_view.xml:142: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'contentDescription' with value '@string/abs__searchview_description_voice').
```

Comment: Do the ActionBarSherlock library project or your own app project show any errors in Eclipse (if that's the IDE that you use)? That could cause the resource file (R.java) not being generated, leading to errors where resources can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you've done: [ActionBarSherlock 4.0 doesn't work. But 3.5.1 do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442781/actionbarsherlock-4-0-doesnt-work-but-3-5-1-do)

The only thing I can remember doing was to set the Project Build Target for my app to be API Level 17 (15 might be good too).

My manifest was:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```